# Switching faculties within a University in Canada

Tags: canada, assistant-professor, professorship, labor-union

If an Assistant Professor switches faculties within the same University, can this change entail a change in salary? Or since the move is within the same (unionized) University, the salary remains the same?

Comment: This depends on your contract, so I think the question should be closed.

Comment: I doubt these nuances are discussed in the contract.

Comment: You should probably reach out to the admin team and ask, we probably wouldn’t know. It could be highly dependent on the university too.

Comment: No competent union would agree to a contract that did not specify a lower limit on every member's pay.  If you cannot figure it out, you should ask your union.  For the contracts I have examined, the answer would be that yes, your salary can change, but only within complicated limitations, and the faculty would not be relevant.